# Hibernate.cgf.xml is not found

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to run the hibrnate code but i will date the error message

```
public class emp
     {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
            //creating configuration object 
            Configuration cfg=new Configuration(); 

        cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
//populates the data of the 

       //creating seession factory object 

        SessionFactory factory=cfg.buildSessionFactory();
        //creating session object

        Session session=factory.openSession(); 

       //creating transaction object

        Transaction t=session.beginTransaction();

        Employee e1=new Employee();

         e1.setId(115);

          e1.setFname("rahul");
          e1.setLastName("jaiswal"); 
          session.persist(e1);
//persisting the object 

t.commit();

//transaction is commited

        session.close();

         System.out.println("successfully saved"); 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The hibernate.cfg.xml file should be in root directory of the classpath of your project. If you using Maven then make sure it should be like

```
src > resources > hibernate.cfg.xml.
```

Otherwise:

Give full path  name of your hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: i am using netbean for the development

Comment: i put the file in my package

Comment: check whether hibernate.cfg.xml is in default package

Comment: I suggest you to check this link:https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/hibernate-webapp.html

Comment: How to solve `hibernate.cfg.xml not found`[reference](http://www.javamakeuse.com/2014/10/orghibernatehibernateexception.html)